# how to fetch commented name on posts in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, comments, relationships, posts

i followed the convention to avail the required data with compact method to view

Schema User Table

```
id,name,email,password
```

Schema post Table

```
id,user_id,title,body
```

Schema comment Table

```
id,post_id,user_id,comments,photo
```

post showing successfully according to users

and comments showing successfully according to posts

but commented name not showing up // please help

how to make relationship for fetch comments with commented user name

please help thanks in advance

Comment: Also post  the code you've tried

Comment: add your code.. logic is true. We should see your code

Comment: how to add my code

Comment: i mean where add my code

Comment: @shiv edit your original post.

Comment: in user model
public function post()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(post::class, 'user_id', 'id');
      }

      public function comments()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(postcomment::class, 'post_id', 'id');
        }

Comment: in post model
Public function User()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(postcomment::class, 'post_id', 'id');

    }

Comment: in comment model
public function posts()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\post');
  }

Comment: in controller

  $list = User::with('post','comments','countcomment','countlikes','fetchName')->where('id' ,'=', $unique_user_id)->paginate(1);

      return view('dynamic',compact('list'));

Comment: in view

@foreach($lists->fetchName as $fetchname)
                      {{$fetchname}}
                    @endforeach